# What is better with virtual machines than with containers?

Tags: virtualization, docker, container

I've been reading up on [Docker](https://www.docker.com/) recently, and I see that there are plenty of reasons to use containerization instead of virtual machines. But what is not talked about as much (since containerization is on it's way up - so people tend to talk about what's so great about it) is what virtual machines does better. Hardware emulation is certainly one thing that is not possible to do with containers, and as far as I know environments can not (as for now) pass through hardware to containers. What else is there to say?

What does virtual machines do better than containerization environments?

Answer (score 0):

- You can run a different OS in virtual machine.
- Better isolation (no host kernel is exposed in virtual machine), better security.
- Docker is not so easy to use if multiple processes run in a container.
- Disk capacity is not easy to expand when a Docker container is created.

Comment: Those two points you mention about limitiations in Docker I believe are things that BSD jails does without any worries (correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: @lindhe I'm not familiar with the FreeBSD jail. I think you asked about Docker specifically.